# Replacing rose ceiling fixture with new light

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, rewire

So unsure if this can be answered but worth a try!

I am replacing my living room light fixtures - they are currently rose ceiling fixtures.

There are two lights in the room that are controlled by one switch. The first fixture has two flex’s coming through the ceiling, each with the 3 wires (live neutral earth). The second fixture has just the one flex.

It is this first fixture I am unsure about. My new fixture has just the three wire points so I effectively have 6 wires and 3 holes.

Now Everywhere I’ve read suggests that the first light  should have 3 flex’s the power in, the loop out and a switch wire. Firstly is this assumption correct?

The flat has two other rose fixtures in different rooms controlled by different switches.

Should it be the case that because the first fixture in the living room has 2 flex’s and the second fixture has just one, that these are on their own loop and one of the flex’s in the first fixture must be the switch wire? (Note that there was no colouring on the wiring that identifies one of these as the live switch).

It might also be worth mentioning that there are spotlights in the kitchen(open plan) controlled by a switch on the same panel.

Can anyone advise whether one of the two flex’s coming into my first rose fixture is a switch wire, and if so if I can identify which one loops to the second fixture (by checkin in the loft or by pulling the second fixture wire and seeing which one it moves) then the other one must be the switch and therefore the neutral wire should be considered the live switch?

I hope this makes sense. Happy to clarify! Thanks in advance

Comment: In a switch loop, there is usually black tape marked white wire to indicate it is a switch loop (switched hot)

Comment: Except the wiring schemes used in the UK are _totally_ different to what we use in the US, @Ruskes. OP is obviously not US based, as we rarely/don't use terms like "flex", "rose", "holes", and we definitely do _not_ put a "u" in color as the OP has.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the pics of the wiring you took _before_ you started disassembling everything. Also include the pics of what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the power goes to the switch first, instead of the light first.  This also means there is neutral at the switch if you go with smart switches in the future.  Only the live wires should be on/connected to the switch.  The neutral wires are just connected together in the switch box.

Turn off the power at the breaker, never trust switches, and take pictures of the wire connection as you remove the old light fixtures.

Connect the new light fixtures as the old ones were and turn on the breaker.  Enjoy your new lights.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Ok so In this case how do I wire? Which live wire should go into the new fixture? Main flex or loop flex?  And should I use wago (or similar) boxes for the other? Or should I connect the two wires from each flex together (ie both live, both neutral etc.) and put into the new fitting as one?

Comment: If the power is coming from the switch, the live is really a switched live, can be confirm with a voltage tester, it will be only live with the switch on.  If so then all lives will be connected together with wire nuts or wagos, same with neutrals, and all grounds